# Query to retrieve the latest status of each action

Tags: c#, linq

I'm new about LinQ technologies. My program generates actions (moving files, deleting files, ...) and saves the status of each action in a database. Let's say that the statutes are simply  passed (1) or failed (0). While my action isn't a success I try it again. For each trial I write a line in my database :

```
ID  ProcessedOn             ActionID  Description  Status
--- ----------------------- --------- ------------ ------
20  2011-05-20 10:45:01.440 24871     xxx          0 
21  2011-05-20 10:45:09.080 24873     xxx          0 
22  2011-05-20 11:00:01.993 24871     xxx          0 
23  2011-05-20 11:00:10.477 24873     xxx          1 
24  2011-05-20 11:15:08.127 24871     xxx          1
```

I would like to write a LINQ query to retrieve the latest status of each action between 2 moment. Is this possible?

I already wrote this :

```
 MyTable.Where(t => t.ProcessedOn >= start).Where(t => t.ProcessedOn <=
 stop).OrderBy(t => t.ProcessedOn).ToList();
```

This request requires an additional condition to keep only the last status. I need to keep the ProcessedOn greater time for each ActionID.

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575316/linq-top-value-form-each-group

Answer (score 4):

You may try to group by ActionID and than fetch only last item

```
MyTable
   .Where(t => t.ProcessedOn >= start)
   .Where(t => t.ProcessedOn <= stop)
   .GroupBy(t => t.ActionID)
   .Select(t => t.OrderBy(t => t.ProcessedOn).Last())
   .ToList();
```

Comment: +1: One minor problem - need inner `OrderBy(t)` lambda to have different variable name because `t` is already used in outer `Select(t)`.

Comment: @mellamokb : uups. This is my fault. I wrote this in answer section without any checking :(  Thank You

Answer (score 3):

You want to make use of the `GroupBy` operator:

```
MyTable
    .Where(t => t.ProcessedOn >= start && t.ProcessedOn <= stop)
    .GroupBy(t => t.ActionID)
    .Select(g => new {
        Action = g.Key,
        LastStatus =
            g.Where(a => a.ProcessedOn == g.Max(a2 => a2.ProcessedOn) )
                .Single().Status
    })
    .ToList();
```