# Linq Query for Top 10 with Group BY

Tags: c#, linq

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Linq - Top value form each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575316/linq-top-value-form-each-group)

I have data in the following structure:

```
 var lookupDictionary = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, double>>();
```

I'm trying to write a Linq query to give me the Top 10 keys from the outer dictionary by summing up and ordering descending the doubles in the inner dictionary.  I have a good grasp on `group by` in SQL, but struggle converting that to Linq.

Any Linq experts that can demonstrate this type of query?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575316/linq-top-value-form-each-group

Comment: It would really make things clearer if you could give an example of your sample input and expected output.

Comment: Also, http://www.WhatHaveYouTried.com/

Comment: Thanks for the link alliswell. I didn't see that one in my initial search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you need a group by?

```
var top = lookupDictionary
    .Select(dict => new { dict.Key, InnerCount = dict.Value.Values.Sum() })
    .OrderByDescending(dict => dict.InnerCount)
    .Take(10);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, double>> lookupDictionary = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, double>>();
lookupDictionary.Select(outerKeyPair => new
{
    Key = outerKeyPair.Key,
    Sum = outerKeyPair.Value.Values.Sum()
})
.OrderByDescending(pair => pair.Sum)
.Take(10);
```