# Using linq to retrieve average score

Tags: c#, linq

was hoping for a little help.

I am retrieving the following list from a database.

```
Name  AssessNumber Score
John     1            90
John     2            88
John     3            67
Steve    1            98
Steve    2            90
```

what I want is to group by average scores and display highest asessment number(int)

```
Name   AssessNumber   Score
John   3              81.6
Steve  2              94
```

The data will be stored in a `List<lbResults>lb = new List<lbResults>()`

How can I achieve this?

kind Regards

Comment: Should be doable with a straighforward `group by`. What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: hint : http://stackoverflow.com/a/1575413/1004522

Comment: seems like `group by average score` will produce a lot of 1-item groups

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
var results = data.GroupBy(x => x.Name).Select(x => new
{
    Name = x.Key,
    AssessNumber = x.Max(z => z.AssessNumber),
    Score = x.Average(z => z.Score)
})
```

You can also return the original data structure (which you named `lbResults`):

```
var results = data.GroupBy(x => x.Name).Select(x => new lbResults
{
    Name = x.Key,
    AssessNumber = x.Max(z => z.AssessNumber),
    Score = x.Average(z => z.Score)
})
```

See [Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Np9dEk)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:-

```
List<lblResults> result = data.GroupBy(x => x.Name)
                              .Select(x => new lbResults 
                                          { 
                                             Name = x.Key, 
                                             AssessNumber = x.Max(z => z.AssesName), 
                                             Score = x.Average(s => s.Score) 
                                          }
                                       ).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

> I want is to group by average scores

From the output it looks like you want to group by `Name` and get the Max `AssessNumber` and average `Score`. Your query should be:

```
var query = lb.GroupBy(r => r.Name)
              .Select(grp => new 
                  {
                     Name = grp.Key, 
                     AccessNumber = grp.Max(i=> i.AccessNumber), 
                     AverageScore = grp.Avg(i => i.Score),
                  });
```

Answer (score 2):

Given:

```
public class lbResults
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Assess { get; set; }
    public int Score { get; set; }
}
```

you want:

```
 List<lbResults> lb = new List<lbResults>
 {
      new lbResults{ Name="John", Assess = 1, Score=90},
      new lbResults{ Name="John", Assess = 2, Score=88},
      new lbResults{ Name="John", Assess = 3, Score=67},
      new lbResults{ Name="Steve", Assess = 1, Score=98},
      new lbResults{ Name="Steve", Assess = 2, Score=90},
 };

var results = lb.GroupBy(l => l.Name)
                .Select(g => new 
                        { 
                          Name = g.Key, 
                          Assess = g.Max(gr => gr.Assess), 
                          Score = g.Average(gr => gr.Score) 
                        });
```

Comment: I like this as an answer. Could you possibly talk through what's going on with the .Max(gr => gr.Assess) and the .Average(gr => gr.Score). What is gr short for?

Comment: `gr` is an arbitrary name i gave to the parameter required for `Max` and `Average`.  Same as the arbitrary names `l` and `g` i used.

Answer (score 0):

Lets have players:

```
var players = new List<Player> {
    new Player { Name = "John",  AssessNumber = 1, Score = 90 },
    new Player { Name = "John",  AssessNumber = 2, Score = 88 },
    new Player { Name = "John",  AssessNumber = 3, Score = 67 },
    new Player { Name = "Steve", AssessNumber = 1, Score = 98 },
    new Player { Name = "Steve", AssessNumber = 2, Score = 90 },
};
```

This code shows grouping using **linq query expression syntax**:

```
var playerInfos =
    from player in players
    group player by player.Name into playerGroup
    select new
    {
        PlayerName = playerGroup.Key,
        MaxAssessNumber = playerGroup.Max(x => x.AssessNumber),
        AverageScore = playerGroup.Average(x => x.Score),
    };
```

The result `playerInfos` is collection of anonymous objects:

```
{ PlayerName = "John",  MaxAssessNumber = 3, AverageScore = 81.66666... }
{ PlayerName = "Steve", MaxAssessNumber = 2, AverageScore = 94.0 }
```

See more info about [LINQ Average](http://www.csharp-examples.net/linq-average/) aggregate method.